# Assigning name to index when using groupby() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have weather data over a variety of years. In this I am trying to find the long term averages for the temperature of each month, which I achieved using the following.

```
mh3 = mh3.groupby([mh3.index.month, mh3.index.day])
mh3 = mh3[['dry_bulb_tmp_mean', 'global_horiz_radiation']].mean()
```

However, in doing this, I get two index's for the dataframe (both month and day which is fine). The issue is that both of these index columns are assigned the name date. Is there a way to manually add a name? This causes problems later in my code when I need to do some data analysis by month. Thank you

Comment: `mh3.index.names = ['month', 'day']`

Answer (score 2):

The `name` of the `Series` you group with becomes the name of the `Index` levels so rename them in the grouper.

```
mh3 = mh3.groupby([mh3.index.month.rename('month'), mh3.index.day.rename('day')])
```

---

Or if you don't want to type as much you can create the grouping with a list comprehension, `getattr` and renaming to the attribute.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='4H', periods=10), 
                  data={'col1': range(10)})

grpr = [getattr(df.index, attr).rename(attr) for attr in ['month', 'day']]
df.groupby(grpr).sum()
#           col1
#month day      
#1     1      15
#      2      30
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That fixed my issue :)